# Diagonalize the cyclic shift operator

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, permutation-matrices, circulant-matrices

Diagonalize the following $n \times n$ matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  0&1&0&&&\dots&&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  &&0&1\\
  &&&0&1\\
  &&&&0&\ddots\\
  &&&&&\ddots&\ddots\\
  1&&&&&&&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I have so far found that it is unitary, and by the spectral theorem it is conjugate to some diagonal matrix. But I have no idea what that matrix is.

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
  -\lambda&1&0&\dots&&&&0\\
  0&-\lambda&1\\
  &&-\lambda&1\\
  &&&-\lambda&1\\
  &&&&-\lambda&\ddots\\
  &&&&&\ddots&\ddots\\
  1&&&&&&&-\lambda\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0 = \lambda^n-1$$

$\therefore \lambda^n=1$ then I get that the only eigenvector is $v=(1,\dots,1)$ which makes the matrix non-diagonalizable. I figure that I am not supposed to be trying to solve this literally but I don't know any relevant parts of spectral theorem to create a diagonalization

Comment: $\lambda^n=1$ has $n$ solutions in the complex numbers.

Comment: I found the eigenvectors for each eigenvalue in general form. where $x_j=(1, \lambda_j, \lambda_j^2, ... , \lambda_j^{N-1})$ How do I use this to diagonalize the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve this problem first over the field of complex numbers. You have successfully found the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^n=1$, so we know that the the matrix has $n$ complex eigenvectors $\lambda_k=e^{2\pi ik/n}$ and you have also found the eigenvectors of form $v_k = (1,\lambda_k,\ldots,\lambda_k^{n-1})$.

So that gives you a diagonal matrix $D$ and transformation matrix $S$:
$$
D = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&\lambda_2&\cdots&0\\
\vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots\\0&0&\cdots&\lambda_n  \end{pmatrix},
\qquad
S=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\begin{pmatrix}1&\lambda_1&\lambda_1^2&\cdots&\lambda_1^{n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&\lambda_n&\lambda_n^2&\cdots&\lambda_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

When you consider this problem over the field of real numbers, the fact that $\lambda^n=1$ has complex solution gives you an idea, that the matrix is not diagonalizable.